# How to compute the loss normal function (not standard normal distribution)

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value, loss-functions

I am struggling with computing the expression of the following term:

$E[x-Q]^+$

where $x$ is a normal r.v with mean $\mu$ and variance $V^2$. Here $[x-Q]^+ = \max \{0, x-Q\}$.

I want to express it as a function of $\mu$, $V^2$ with parameter $Q$.

Answer (score 4):

So, we have $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$ and are interested in the loss
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
   L(\mu,\sigma;Q)= \E \left[ X-Q\right]^+
$$
First, note that if we have found the loss in the standard normal case then
$$
L(\mu,\sigma;Q)= \E \left[X-Q\right]^+ =\sigma\E\left[ \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} -\frac{Q-\mu}{\sigma}\right]^+=\sigma L(0,1;\frac{Q-\mu}{\sigma})
$$
and then for the standard normal case:
$$
L(0,1;Q)=\int_Q^\infty (x-Q)\phi(x)\; dx =\int_Q^\infty x\phi(x)\; dx -Q \int_Q^\infty \phi(x)\; dx = [-\phi(x)]_Q^\infty -Q(1-\Phi(Q))=
\phi(Q) + Q(\Phi(Q)-1)=\phi(Q)-Q+Q\Phi(Q)
$$
where $\phi, \Phi$ are standard normal density and cdf.